# LinkedList update performance in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

In this below piece of code, i find removing the first listnode always and printing the first node is more efficient(in terms of execution time) than keeping the list intact and iterating over all nodes. I was wondering this is because when I always remove the first node I just have to update the start node to next node and just fetch the first node to print the value. In case of iterating over the entire list by keeping list intanct, the get operation is traversing the list everytime to the specified index and fetching the value.
Now my questions are:
1) Is my understanding correct?
2) Do both ways should execute in same time
3) Is there any other reasoning?

```
public class Ddbrw {
public List<Integer> ListValidation()
    {
        List<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
        lst.add(new Integer(1)); lst.add(new Integer(5));
        lst.add(new Integer(9)); lst.add(new Integer(7));
        lst.add(new Integer(5)); lst.add(new Integer(61));
        lst.add(new Integer(8)); lst.add(new Integer(12));
        }
        return lst;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Ddbrw obj = new Ddbrw();
    Ddbrw obj2 = new Ddbrw();

    List<Integer> lst = obj2.ListValidation();
    int size = lst.size();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(lst.get(i));
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("*************");
    System.out.println(endTime-startTime);
    System.out.println("*************");

    List<Integer> lst2 = obj.ListValidation();
    long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int k = 0; k < lst2.size(); ) {
        System.out.print(lst2.get(k));
        lst2.remove(k);
    }
    long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("*************");
    System.out.println(endTime1-startTime1);
    System.out.println("*************");
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Integer(1)` never use this, always use `Integer.valueof(1)`. This is true for most boxed primitives. Also, this is not how you benchmark a Java program; You have to warm-up the JVM.

Comment: Better yet, just use `1`. E.g., `lst.add(1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial reasoning is correct, the point is that a `LinkedList` is not meant to be efficient with random access. So every time you access an element by index (eg `lst.get(k)`) you have to reach that element from the beginning of the list.

But this doesn't mean that a `LinkedList` can't be used efficiently in your situation, it is just that you are trying to use it as an `ArrayList`. `List<T>` provides `Iterator<T>` which is more efficient when iterating over the list.

For example:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = lst.iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
  System.out.println(it.next());

for (int i : lst)
  System.out.println(i);
```

This will iterate the list without having to reach the `k`-th element on each iteration since it keeps track of everything inside the iterator.

Actually this could be even more efficient than an `ArrayList` under some circumstances since it doesn't have to memmove/shift the successive elements everytime you remove an element.

Comment: OP doesn't care to remove elements. It was just a gimmick to get constant time with an index lookup.

Comment: Yes, but the point doesn't change. The point is that the OP should use `Iterator<T>` which will provide the most suitable way to iterate over a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct specifically with regards to a linked list, and only because you're traversing by index. Java has a [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface to identify `List` implementations that can be indexed in constant time, which is implemented by `ArrayList` for example, but not by `LinkedList`.

If you used an iterator to traverse the list instead, you would get approximately the same performance:

```
for (Integer i : lst) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.